# Backup on TFS Release before deploying

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

i'm kinda noobie with the TFS build/releases.
So my scenario:

I have a build phase which is making an artifact. This artifact is deployed on a Virtual Azure Machine after some changes.

My question is : is there any possibility to make a backup of the release of the previous version of the artifact, just to ensure if the Release Failed, to put the previous version back? 
Is this based on the artifact or something or do i need to to it manually, with archive, copy , pasting etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you select artifact during the release create process. You are able to select any version of your build instead of latest.

[image]

Regarding **backup**, you can add a Powershell task to perform a backup of the original files or generated artifacts.

There are also a [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and a [Zip Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) task which you can drop into your process. For example copy your `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` to a file share to back up your artifacts. You can even make the tasks conditional.

However, there is no build-in "**rollback**" task, the normal thing to do would be to schedule a new release with the previous version to install. Or use a powershell script to invoke Rest API to create a new release.

Besides, you could also choose to install this [Release Management Utility Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) extension, you’ll see a new task called “Rollback powershell” in the task catalog. For rollback, you’ll need to add this task to the workflow.

Here is a useful blog for your reference: [Implement Rollback with Release Management for TFS 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/28/implement-rollback-with-release-management-for-tfs-2015/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the build retention policy.  You could do something like Days to keep = 365 and Minimum to keep = 3.  Then you will always have at least 3 build back.